cleveref and longtable incompatibility
It turns out that cleveref does not work well with the longtable environment in TeX Live 2024 (whereas it worked perfectly in the 2023 version). Is there any solution to this bug?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\caption{Example of a longtable} \label{tab:example} \\
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
1 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

Reference to \cref{tab:example}.

Reference to \Cref{tab:example}.

\end{document}



the \label should be inside the `\caption (which is enough to make it write to the aux file) but cref still doesn't pick it up for some reason, looking...

it worked in texlive 2023

@Mico thanks, I was about to ping Ulrike but now I have better reason:-)
